# Shiny: Change column used in ggplot2 dynamically

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I tried creating a Shiny app where you can choose the x-Axis of a `ggplot` per 'selectizeInput'.

I know about the [Gallery Example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/kmeans-example.html), where this was solved by pre-selecting the desired column. Because in my case the data structure is a bit complex I would prefer, when it is possible to change the `x =` attribute in `aes()` dynamically.

For better understanding I added a minimal working example. Unfortunately `ggplot` uses the input as value, instead to use the corresponding column.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Select x Axis"),       

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectizeInput("xaxis", 
                       label = "x-Axis",
                       choices = c("carat", "depth", "table"))            
      ),          

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("Plot")
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   output$Plot <- renderPlot({
     p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = input$xaxis, y = price))
     p <-p + geom_point()
     print(p)
   })
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Use `aes_` or `aes_string`, see `?aes_`. It would become `ggplot(diamonds, aes_string(x = input$xaxis, y = 'price'))`.

Comment: Works perfectly, didn't kown about `aes_()`.  If you post it as an answere I will mark it as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`aes` uses NSE (non-standard evaluation). This is great for interactive use, but not so great for programming with. For this reason, there are two SE (standard evaluation) alternatives, `aes_` (formerly `aes_q`) and `aes_string`. The first takes quoted input, the second string input. In this case, the problem can be quite easily solved by using `aes_string` (since `selectizeInput` gives us a string anyways).

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes_string(x = input$xaxis, y = 'price')) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: As `aes_string` is becoming deprecated, the it's good to know about the alternatives `!!as.symbol()` and `!!rlang:sym()` as listed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60627768/2166823