# R shiny error when using reactive to plot

Tags: r, plot, reactive

I have this data set:

```
Area <- c("Mexico", "USA", "USA", "Canada").

Type_of_participants <- c("Doctor", "Doctor", "Engineer", "Dancer".

Salary <- c("4000", "6000", "8000", "5000").
```

and I am trying to plot the salary base on the user input of Area(level1) and Type_of_participants(level2), but nothing appears. I modified aes to aes_string as I looked up here. Please help me find the error

My Code

```
`ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Survey Results"),
   sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(strong("Overview Plot"),
             br(),
             ###1a.Area input
             selectInput("selection","Var",
                          choices = c("Area","Type_of_participants"),
                          selected = "Area"),
            uiOutput("choice_selection")      
),
mainPanel(    
  plotOutput("Overview"))

`server <- function(input, output) {
   output$choice_selection <- renderUI({
   checkboxGroupInput("baseinput","Detail",
                   unique(df[,input$selection])
                  )`
   })
    dt1 <- reactive({
   df %>%
    group_by(input$selection,Type) %>%
     filter (input$selection %in% input$baseinput) %>%
     summarise(avg_salary_by_area = mean(Salary, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
     select(input$selection, Type, avg_Salary_by_area)
      })

    output$Overview <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data= dt1())+
     aes(fill = Type)+
      geom_bar(x=input$selection, y = avg_salary_by_area,stat="identity", 
           position = position_dodge())
```

The result is I can select the input but can not visualize the plot. The error "unknown column Area or unknow Type of participants

Please help me find the mistake

Thank you

*** Update

Thanks to Mr Flick, I have fixed my code but it still informs error "Object area not found". Please help to advise. Thank you so much

```
  `dt1 <- reactive({
  df[df[,input$selection] %in% input$baseinput,] %>%
  group_by(input$selection,Type) %>%
  summarise(avg_score_by_area = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE))
  })

 output$Overview <- renderPlot({

 ggplot(data= dt1(),aes_string(x= input$selection, 
                              y = "avg_score_by_area",fill = "Type"))+
 geom_bar(stat="identity", 
           position = position_dodge())`
```

Comment: Your server function doesn't seem to be complete. Maybe this will help: [Shiny: Change column used in ggplot2 dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431708/shiny-change-column-used-in-ggplot2-dynamically)

Comment: And also [R Shiny - Using Selectinput as column selection to subset data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532858/r-shiny-using-selectinput-as-column-selection-to-subset-data-frame)

Comment: Hi, Thank very much for your help. I tried to modify my code as below. It still have error "object 'Area' not found". Please advise

    dt1 <- reactive({
      df[df[,input$selection] %in% input$baseinput,] %>%
      group_by(input$selection,Type) %>%
      summarise(avg_salary_by_area = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE))
      })

    output$Overview <- renderPlot({
        
   ggplot(data= dt1(),aes_string(x= input$selection, 
                                  y = "avg_salary_by_area",fill = "Type"))+
   geom_bar(stat="identity", 
               position = position_dodge())

Comment: Hi @Suzie - please do not post code in comments. Rather, please edit the question to reflect its new state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Suzie - as mentioned above, it would help if you edited your question with your complete code as you currently have it.

A few things that would help:

- Salary should be numeric in your `df` (or be converted with `as.numeric` before trying to take the mean
- Your `reactive` expression can use `!!as.symbol` with `input$selection` to filter by the string name from `df`
- The plot can use `aes_string` for the variable names.

**Edit**:

For further explanation of `!!as.symbol`, first consider what the result of `input$selection`. If you use `browser()` in your shiny code, and inspect what `input$selection` returns, you will see something like `"Area"` (it returns a string). But a string would not be appropriate in your `filter` - it is expecting a symbol that represents a column in your data frame. (A symbol is the name of an object like `df` or `mtcars`, etc.)

First, you want to convert a string to a symbol. You can do that either by using `as.symbol()` or `rlang::sym()`. You can try this out in your console. If you do `as.symbol("df")` it would return the symbol `df`. If you entered `eval(as.symbol("df"))` it would be the same as just entering `df` itself (and it would show the contents of your data frame).

The other issue is that `tidyverse` functions evaluate code expressions in a special context (searching for names within a data frame, for example). In this case `dplyr` knows that the name `Area` is in the context of `df` (one of the column names). This is a complicating factor since arguments are quoted. To address this, you need to unquote (replace a name with its value) with the bang-bang `!!` operator.

Putting both together you get `!!as.symbol()`.

Of note, `varSelectInput` is a newer shiny alternative to `selectInput` that can be considered for use in situations like these.

For more information:

[shinymeta special topics](https://rstudio.github.io/shinymeta/articles/special-topics.html)

[advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/expressions.html)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

Area <- c("Mexico", "USA", "USA", "Canada")
Type_of_participants <- c("Doctor", "Doctor", "Engineer", "Dancer")
Salary <- c(4000, 6000, 8000, 5000)

df <- data.frame(Area, Type_of_participants, Salary)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Survey Results"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(strong("Overview Plot"),
                 br(),
                 ###1a.Area input
                 selectInput("selection","Var",
                             choices = c("Area","Type_of_participants"),
                             selected = "Area"),
                 uiOutput("choice_selection")      
    ),
    mainPanel(    
      plotOutput("Overview")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$choice_selection <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("baseinput", "Detail", unique(df[,input$selection]))
  })

  dt1 <- reactive({
    df %>%
      group_by(Area, Type_of_participants) %>%
      filter(!!as.symbol(input$selection) %in% input$baseinput) %>%
      summarise(avg_salary_by_area = mean(Salary, na.rm = TRUE))
  })

  output$Overview <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = dt1(), aes_string(x = input$selection, y = "avg_salary_by_area", fill = "Type_of_participants")) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Could you please explain a bit more about the syntax !!as.symbol(input$selection) here as I am still a bit confused about this and not much of documentation on the internet about it :(  Appreciate it :)

Comment: @Suzie see edited answer for additional explanation.